# The token received from AAD was not recognized as a valid JWT

Tags: angularjs, azure, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, azure-active-directory

I am developing an Angular website hosted in Azure that interacts with a separate Web API back-end, also hosted in Azure.  I am attempting to use a combination of ASP .Net Identity w/ OAuth Bearer Tokens in the Web API layer for user account login / authentication, and also Azure Active Directory in the website layer, to control access to the application itself, since it's not live and I do not want it to be accessible to the general public.

Everything was working fine, until I added the AAD logic. Now for some reason, after I log-in with a user account via the Web API, I get the following server-side exception in the website for two specific .html files that angular tries load while navigating the user to their account dashboard. I can load these files directly via the URL, and all the other files required by that page seem to load correctly, but these two return this error.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the
current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information
about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The token received from
AAD was not recognized as a valid JWT.

Source Error:
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web
request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can
be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace: [InvalidOperationException: The token received from AAD was not
recognized as a valid JWT.]
    Microsoft.Azure.Websites.Authentication.AADAuthenticationModule.OnValidateJwt(String rawToken, Boolean validateNonce) +845
    Microsoft.Azure.Websites.Authentication.AADAuthenticationModule.TryAuthenticateFromBearerToken(HttpRequestBase request, IPrincipal& principal) +157
    Microsoft.Azure.Websites.Authentication.AADAuthenticationModule.TryAuthenticate(HttpContextBase context, IPrincipal& principal) +34
    Microsoft.Azure.Websites.Authentication.AADAuthenticationModule.AuthenticateRequest(HttpContextBase context) +578
    Microsoft.Azure.Websites.Authentication.AADAuthenticationModule.OnAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +80
    System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +136
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +69

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.36215
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

OK, so I don't know if this is the correct answer to this issue, but I ended up changing my Angular code so that instead of adding the Bearer token to the global headers collection (which angular then transmits with every request, including templates and resources), I now manually add it only for the GET / POST requests to the Web API endpoints.

**Was**

```
$http.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = 'Bearer ' + token;
```

**Now**

```
_self.Get = function(url, data, token)
{
    var _request = {
        method: "GET",
        url: url,
        data: data
    };

    if (token != null)
    {
        _request.headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token };
    }

    return $http(_request);
};
```